# SEO friendly book sharing website built with angular.js

Tags: seo, crawlable-ajax

I have a book sharing website which is built with angular. The basic model is that someone creates a book entry on my site and that book gets displayed on the front page of the website, along with a discover page. On these pages one can then click on the cover of the showcased books which will directly take you the book's homepage (within my site) containing all of the book's information.

Now the problem comes when trying to make my website SEO friendly, and it has boiled down to two options. I could have a headless browser pre-render my page or I could leave the bot on its own to interpret my page on its own.

The caveat of the first option, is firstly that google has deprecated this method of doing things since it uses the `_escaped_fragment=` parameter, but most importantly is the fact that the front page of my site can contain up to 300+ book entries, and my discover page can contain even significantly more. So if I went with a headless browser to render the pages for the crawler I could potentially overload and crash the server if it tries to render the homepage for every entry at the time the crawler is requesting them.

The second approach which is ideal but I have not gotten it to work would be to have the angular data binding work on its own. Where on the front page I could have the entries and within the entry embed a hidden `<a>` tag that binds to the entries homepage, however since the entries are loaded with AJAX the crawler requests the unmodified url, instead of the resolved one. This is also a problem within the book's homepage where the meta tags are interpolated to include the book's individual descriptions, but all the crawler sees are the unresolved versions.

Therefore I am truly between a rock and a hard place when it comes to SEO, which my site would greatly benefit from since the book's would have a greater chance of being discovered if they were to appear whenever someone searched for keywords that don't necessarily pertain to my website's functionality but rather to the book's description. Any suggestions are appreciated.